# Access object attribute with variable?

Tags: php, sql

Not sure if the title is exactly what i want to do. Below is my working code.

```
        mysql_select_db($_POST[database]);
        $table_list = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        $tables_in_db = "Tables_in_" . $_POST[database];
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($table_list)) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td class='pageBody'>" . $row->$tables_in_db . "</td>
                  </tr>";
        }
```

Is it possible to remove line 4 and access the object attribute with $row->Tables_in_{$_POST[database]} in some manner? I've tried a couple different ways including various placing of quotes and curly braces, i had to resort to assigning the whole attribute to the variable $tables_in_db and then use that variable to access the attribute.

Comment: **mysql_select_db($_POST['database']);** is just begging to be exploited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, just not the proper syntax. Variable properties can either take the form of a single variable (`$a->$b`) or some other expression that returns a string containing the name of the property (`$a->{'b'}`).

```
$row->{'Tables_in_' . $_POST['database']}
```

Aside: using one of the other `mysql_fetch_*` functions, knowing the column name would become irrelevant. For example, `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_row()` and accessing the `$row[0]` item.