# PHP set data by var name

Tags: php

I have class

```
class User extends BaseModel{
     public $id;
     public $name;
}

class BaseModel{
     function __construct($data=null){
          if($data!=null)
          //set $id and $name
     }
}
```

I would like to set $id , $name and any other data that extends BaseModel by calling

```
$test = new User(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'user name'))
```

I tried to use

```
$this->__set($arrayKey,$arrayValue);
```

But i got error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::__set()
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access object attribute with variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692162/access-object-attribute-with-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the data and assign each property:

```
class BaseModel {
     function __construct($data = NULL) {
          foreach ((array) $data as $k => $v) {
              $this->$k = $v;
          }
     }
}
```

The reason you got the error about `__set()` not being defined is because you didn't define it. Although `__set()` is a magic method, you do still have to define it's behavior if you want to do something with it.

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set
>
> `__set` is run when writing data to inaccessible properties

This means if you try to "set" a class variable in a scope you're not allowed to (like a private or protected variable), this function will run.

```
class Test {
    private $var;
}

$c = new Test;
$c->var = 1; // Error, or call __set if defined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $this->$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a lot simpler then i thought it would be.
One more thing, could you please tell me how can i find out if variable is declared. When i use isset it returns false, because variable is null, but it is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class BaseModel{
     function __construct($data=null){
          if($data!=null)
        {
          //set $id and $name
          $this->id = $data['id'];
          $this->name = $data['name'];
        }
     }
}
```